# Add a dtd using nokogiri builder

Tags: xml, ruby, nokogiri, dtd

I am using `nokogiri` to generate svg pictures. I would like to add the correct xml preamble and svg DTD declaration to get something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"> 
<svg>
...
```

With `builder` I could use `instruct!` and `declare!` but I want to stick with `nokogiri` because I use it for other purpose in my project and I want to stay low on requirements. Do you have some ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now (don't know from which version) use Node#create_internal_subset to create the DTD node. For more info see: http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html

And scroll down to the "Document Types" section for an example.

Comment: The link is dead :/

Comment: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder

Answer (score 5):

Following is from a note at the bottom of the [Nokogiri::XML::Builder page](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html) (maybe added recently), which I think will do the trick:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.doc.create_internal_subset(
    'html',
    "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN",
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"
  )
  xml.root do
    xml.foo
  end
end

puts builder.to_xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, though it looks like a dirty trick:

```
#1. I build the svg document
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.svg do
    # ...
  end
end

#2. I retrieve the svg root node
svg = builder.doc.xpath("/svg").first

#3. I define and parse an xml document with the required preamble and dtd
str =<<EOS
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1. /DTD/svg11.dtd">
EOS
doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(str)

#4. I add the svg node to the document above
doc.add_child(svg)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those working with HTML, Eric Walkers' example doesn't quite work since a doctype is automatically added. You need to remove it first:

```
builder = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |html|
  html.doc.internal_subset.remove
  html.doc.create_internal_subset('html', nil, nil)
end
```

This will add the HTML5 doctype a.k.a. `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be any way to add a doctype using `Nokogiri::XML::Builder`. However, adding a doctype declaration to an XML document is of dubious utility, unless your tools require it. Read [DTDs Don't Work on the Web by Henri Sivonen](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/no-dtd/) for some reasons why it's not a very good idea to use DTDs, and you should instead ensure your document is well-formed, and validate it against an external schema (which may be a DTD, or may be something more powerful like XSD or RELAX-NG) rather than a DTD embedded within the document.